# iphone development: how to prevent caching in friendspickercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, caching

I have a strange problem with Facebook SDK for iOS. I am going to explain the problem step by step:

1)User opens the app 2)User logins with Facebook Connect 3)User looks his friends by using FriendPickerController 4)user logs out by using the code : `[appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];`
5)user tries to login with different facebook account 6)successfully logs in

Everything is OK so far but when the user tries to load his friends by using FriendPickerController, the friends of the first user appears, it is strange but could not figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem: The problem is although I have no facebook app in my phone, there was a registered facebook account in the settings. so I deleted it and problem solved.